Intento establecer un error en caso que este vacía una variable y no funciona - Batch Script
Estoy generando un código en Batch Script para realizar una automatización.
En un sector del código se obtienen las unidades detectadas por el sistema, y luego de detectarlas, se le muestra al usuario para que pueda elegir entre ellas (En total debe elegir 4 unidades). Si no selecciona nada, le devuelve un error para que vuelva a seleccionar correctamente. Y si selecciona una unidad inexistente, también le devuelve un error para que vuelva a seleccionar. Hasta ahí todo funciona bien.

:select_unit_Start1

::// Restablecimiento y Seteo de Variables-\\\ ◄◄◄◄ 00
@echo off
SET "drive="
SET "drives="
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::// Obtencion de unidades disponibles en la PC-\\\ ◄◄◄◄ 00
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /format:value') do (
    REM Mostrar las unidades separas por una coma
    set "drive=%%d"
    if defined drive (
        set "drive=!drive:~0,1!"
        if defined drives (
            set "drives=!drives!,!drive!"
        ) else (
            set "drives=!drive!"
        )
    )
)

echo Unidades disponibles: %drives%
echo.


El problema está en que cuando el usuario termina de seleccionar la primera unidad, y tiene que continuar con las restantes, si no escribe ninguna opción, se vuelve a seleccionar la misma unidad que se seleccionó anteriormente. Para colmo, en la respuesta echo que se muestra cuando hay una selección, la cual se supone que no tendría ni que aparecer, termina muestrandosela al usuario como si hubiera elegido una unidad, pero en vez de aparecer la unidad anteriormente seleccionada, aparece vacía. (Y me doy cuenta de que a pesar de figurar vacía, sigue tomando la unidad anteriormente seleccionada, ya que tiene un archivo que debe copiar como prueba)
En otras palabras, no está funcionando la devolución de error.
Ya intenté vaciando las variables cuando se debe ejecutar la misma tarea para seleccionar las demas unidades, añadiendo:
SET "drive="
SET "drives="
SET "unit="

Pero tampoco me ha funcionado.
¿Podrian darme una mano para averiguar que es lo que estoy haciendo mal? Muchas Gracias.
Dejo aca abajo el codigo completo:
00-Seleccion-de-unidad

¡ACTUALIZACION!
He encontrado una solución (Parcial). He escrito el código de forma completamente diferente. Esta vez en vez utilizar variables dinámicas como bucles de posición, cree etiquetas para cada paso y genere bucles que se comuniquen con aquellas etiquetas. Peeeeero por alguna razón, a pesar de poder incluso hacer que desaparezcan las unidades luego de ser seleccionadas, se me amontonan todas las "," (comas) juntas. Probé modificando el filtro de eliminación de variable agregando la coma como elemento a tener en cuenta, pero por alguna razón no lo hace. Aun así me gustaría más encontrar la solución al primer diseño que hice, ya que disminuye bastante las líneas.
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Obtener unidades activas de la PC
set "drive_list="
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2 delims==" %%d in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /value') do (
    set "drive=%%d"
    set "drive=!drive:~0,1!"  REM Obtener solo la primera letra de la unidad
    set "drive_list=!drive_list!,!drive!"
)

REM Eliminar la primera coma de la lista
set "drive_list=%drive_list:~1%"

echo Unidades activas: %drive_list%

REM Inicializar variables de selección
set "DiskSelection_Sistema="
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad="
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad="
set "DiskSelection_Datos="

:select_unit_Sistema
cls
echo Seleccione una unidad para Sistema de la lista anterior:
set /p "selected_unit=Unidades activas (%drive_list%): "

REM Validar la selección
set "valid=false"
for %%d in (%drive_list%) do (
    if /I "!selected_unit!"=="%%d" (
        set "valid=true"
        goto :valid_selection_Sistema
    )
)
if "!valid!"=="false" (
    echo La selección no es válida. Por favor, seleccione una unidad de la lista.
    pause
    goto :select_unit_Sistema
)

:valid_selection_Sistema
REM Almacenar selección en variables
set "DiskSelection_Sistema=!selected_unit!"

REM Eliminar la unidad seleccionada de la lista de unidades disponibles
set "drive_list=!drive_list:%selected_unit%=!"

:select_unit_Programas_Alta_Velocidad
cls
echo Seleccione una unidad para Programas Alta Velocidad de la lista anterior:
set /p "selected_unit=Unidades activas (%drive_list%): "

REM Validar la selección
set "valid=false"
for %%d in (%drive_list%) do (
    if /I "!selected_unit!"=="%%d" (
        set "valid=true"
        goto :valid_selection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad
    )
)
if "!valid!"=="false" (
    echo La selección no es válida. Por favor, seleccione una unidad de la lista.
    pause
    goto :select_unit_Programas_Alta_Velocidad
)

:valid_selection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad
REM Almacenar selección en variables
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad=!selected_unit!"

REM Eliminar la unidad seleccionada de la lista de unidades disponibles
set "drive_list=!drive_list:%selected_unit%=!"

:select_unit_Programas_Baja_Velocidad
cls
echo Seleccione una unidad para Programas Baja Velocidad de la lista anterior:
set /p "selected_unit=Unidades activas (%drive_list%): "

REM Validar la selección
set "valid=false"
for %%d in (%drive_list%) do (
    if /I "!selected_unit!"=="%%d" (
        set "valid=true"
        goto :valid_selection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad
    )
)
if "!valid!"=="false" (
    echo La selección no es válida. Por favor, seleccione una unidad de la lista.
    pause
    goto :select_unit_Programas_Baja_Velocidad
)

:valid_selection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad
REM Almacenar selección en variables
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad=!selected_unit!"

REM Eliminar la unidad seleccionada de la lista de unidades disponibles
set "drive_list=!drive_list:%selected_unit%=!"

:select_unit_Datos
cls
echo Seleccione una unidad para Datos de la lista anterior:
set /p "selected_unit=Unidades activas (%drive_list%): "

REM Validar la selección
set "valid=false"
for %%d in (%drive_list%) do (
    if /I "!selected_unit!"=="%%d" (
        set "valid=true"
        goto :valid_selection_Datos
    )
)
if "!valid!"=="false" (
    echo La selección no es válida. Por favor, seleccione una unidad de la lista.
    pause
    goto :select_unit_Datos
)

:valid_selection_Datos
REM Almacenar selección en variables
set "DiskSelection_Datos=!selected_unit!"

REM Eliminar la unidad seleccionada de la lista de unidades disponibles
set "drive_list=!drive_list:%selected_unit%=!"

REM Convertir selecciones en mayúsculas
set "DiskSelection_Sistema=!DiskSelection_Sistema:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad=!DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad=!DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Datos=!DiskSelection_Datos:~0,1!"

REM Mostrar selecciones
echo.
echo Unidades seleccionadas:
echo Sistema: %DiskSelection_Sistema%
echo Programas Alta Velocidad: %DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad%
echo Programas Baja Velocidad: %DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad%
echo Datos: %DiskSelection_Datos%

pause

Por ultimo tambien estoy intentando establecer a Mayusculas las variables alojadas. Pero no las transforma. El metodo que use es el siguiente:
set "DiskSelection_Sistema=!DiskSelection_Sistema:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad=!DiskSelection_Programas_Alta_Velocidad:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad=!DiskSelection_Programas_Baja_Velocidad:~0,1!"
set "DiskSelection_Datos=!DiskSelection_Datos:~0,1!"


Aunque imagino que a estas alturas AdrielXXO ya habrá resuelto sus problemas puede que alguna otra persona pueda estar interesada en este asunto. Voy a centrarme en el script de partida, el que se puede obtener en el enlace facilitado como "00-Seleccion-de-unidad".
Estos son mis comentarios:

Me parece que no tiene mucho sentido repetir cuatro veces el código de obtención de unidades disponibles, una para cada selección, ni tampoco repetirlo cada vez que se produce un error en la elección de unidad, bien porque se deje vacío o porque se indique una unidad que no existe. Por tanto creo que basta con incluir ese código una sola vez al comienzo del script y utilizar las variables que recogen las unidades disponibles cada vez que se necesite hacerlo.
Para impedir que se permita no elegir ninguna unidad sugiero sustituir la línea:
echo %drives% | findstr /i "\<%unit%\>" >nul

por esta otra:
if not "%unit%"=="" echo %drives% | findstr /i "\<%unit%\>" >nul


Para impedir que en caso de no elegir unidad se arrastre la elegida en la elección previa sugiero incluir, antes de cada petición de selección, la línea:
set "unit="


En el código suministrado aparece (con sus 4 variantes, una para cada selección) la línea:
copy "TEST.txt" "%DiskSelectionNucleo%:/"

No se entiende bien que se pretende, pero no se nos facilita el contenido del archivo TEST.txt. Si se quiere añadir a ese archivo la selección en curso sería, más bien, algo como:
echo DiskSelectionNucleo: "%DiskSelectionNucleo%:\" >> TEST.txt


Si no se quiere que se vea el resultado de cada selección (cosa que no me queda muy clara porque tal vez se refiere al caso en que está vacía y se muestra la que se arrastra) bastaría con comentar o borrar la línea (las cuatro variantes):
echo La unidad seleccionada es: %DiskSelectionNucleo%:/


Por último, y aunque no tenga ningún efecto en la ejecución del script, aparece un cierre de paréntesis ")" inútil e innecesario tras cada una de las cuatro variantes de las líneas:
REM Mostrar la unidad seleccionada fuera del bloque else
echo La unidad seleccionada es: %DiskSelectionNucleo%:/
)



